# Dismiss view and set data when didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers, delegate and an array of strings

I have a delegate function meant to set the label on the first VC to the string from the row selected on the table view of the second VC:

```
openSelected(selected: String, viewController: UIVIewController){
label.text = selected
}
```

Here is my didSelectRow function on the second VC:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath){

   var selected = savedStrings[indexPath.row]
    delegate?.openSelected(selected: selected, viewController: self)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The delegate is set up correctly. The table view shows all the strings on different rows. I want the current view to disappear and show my label with the selected string as text when I select a row. However, the row is selected, but nothing happens, and I can continue playing with the table view and selecting new rows and nothing will happen.

Why is the dismiss function not working/actually dismissing the VC? Hope this is enough info. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct method of the table `UITableViewDelegate`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

also make sure in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

//

Make sure

```
class ViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
```

Comment: In assigning the delegate, I am getting the error "Cannot assign value of type ViewController to type 'UITableViewDelegate?'

Comment: I dont' have a UITableViewDelegate set up, only my own protocol I created to pass the data. Is that the problem?

Comment: can you post complete code please